# Python Loops N to 0 or -N to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, scripting

```
We will pass in a value N. N can be positive or negative.

If N is positive then output all values from N down to and excluding 0.
If N is negative, then output every value from N up to and excluding 0.
```

I am stuck on this challenge, and I cannot figure out how to code this or only output the positive or negative values.

Any help?

Comment: Is this for your online class again? Posting questions every day about being stuck at the beginning of an assignment might indicate that you would benefit from a tutor.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Your sarcasm is appreciated (truly), however, this is not the beginning of the assignment, nor is a tutor readily available since it's an ONLINE course, at a school quite a few states away. I thought this website was for asking questions, so I apologize if I've misunderstood. This is an Intro to Scripting class, the professor doesn't answer e-mails or understand how to use Codio, the curriculum doesn't match with the work it asks us to do, and so I am using every resource I can to get help so I don't waste thousands of dollars by failing this class.

Comment: Sorry; I wasn't trying to be sarcastic. If the course doesn't offer much in the way of support beyond included textbooks/slides/etc., a tutor (even an independent tutor) can be a real help. I've tutored several students who were taking online courses or simply having trouble with the supplied materials. If the professor doesn't answer emails, the curriculum is otherwise problematic, you're in for a tough semester, as this site isn't intended to handle daily homework lessons.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Luckily I've been able to figure the rest out on my own and am finished with the semester at the end of the weekend.

Comment: Wonderful - congratulations! I hope you continue with Python; it's a really nice language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check this code and let me know if this works.

```
def printNumber(num):
    #If N is positive then output all values from N down to and excluding 0.
    if num > 0:
        for i in range(num, 0, -1):
            print(i)
    #If N is negative then output all values from N up to and excluding 0.
    else:
        for i in range(num, 0):
            print(i)

printNumber(-5)
printNumber(5)
```

Comment: Not quite. I adjusted it below:

Comment: `import sys
N = int(sys.argv[1])

# Your code goes here

def printNumber(N):
    if N > 0:
        for i in range(0, N):
            print(i)
    else:
        for i in range(-N, 0):
            print(i)

printNumber(-13)
printNumber(13)`

Comment: It's close, but it's printing the '0', so I am just messing around with it now.

Comment: Your code is still wrong, and you have provided zero explanation. This is not helpful.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 can you please tell me what is wrong with my code. It will be really helpful.

Comment: Look at the task, then check your code's output. And, again, there is no explanation here for a student who's trying to learn the material.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Sure, I will add explanation but can you tellme what is wrong with my code.

Comment: It is your responsibility to take a few seconds to read questions properly before posting an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189166/discussion-between-mayank-bansal-and-tigerhawkt3).